# Why am I receiving this compiler error. The syntax appears correct to me

Tags: php, wordpress, compiler-errors

I'm receiving the following error on my wordpress site:

*An error of type E_PARSE was caused in line 56 of the file /var/www/compass.valuescentre.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php. Error message: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{'*

Below is my code from line 56-58:

`function wc_get_container() : \Psr\Container\ContainerInterface { return $GLOBALS['wc_container']; }`

Comment: We probably need to see the previous few lines as well.

Comment: Check the version of PHP as function return types may not be supported.

Answer (score -1):

A compiler gets problems on the exact location of a missing ),},; or ].
I would advice you to look if you missed any closing tags in the lines before 56.
if you whant to make that fast, maybe go with control + f to look for the amount of opening brakets and see if it matches the closing ones?
good luck!

Comment: Great, thank you! That helped.